# Ways to simulate light dispersion in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shaders, lighting, glass

I've been attempting to create a triangular prism exhibiting light dispersion, and have found sources suggesting the use of three glass shaders, using red, green, and blue, each with a slightly different IOR. It works well enough, but for more complex refraction over a greater distance, the light spreads into multiple red, green, and blue dots. I was thinking of using math nodes to get a unique IOR from each hue value, but I am unsure of how to implement it. Has anyone tried anything similar before? Or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Comment: White noise texture is the modern solution.  I worked on an example for nodevember two years ago but ran out of time.  Here's the video I was using as reference and trying to improve upon
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEPZ1IUkoB4

Comment: It might be helpful to people trying to help you if you uploaded an example blend file to the site https://blend-exchange.com and add that link in the question.